# Arrows at intersection in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, intersections

I want to have the arrow tips on the intersection between the rectangle and the lines. Here I've got a M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip[draw] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
        \path[name path=a] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
%       \draw[name path=b] (1.5,1.5) --+ (-2,2);
%           \path[name intersections={of=a and b,by=s}];
%       \node[fill=red,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (s) {};
        \foreach \x in {0,10,...,350}
        {
            \draw[name path=\x,shift={(1.5,1.5)}] (0,0) -- (\x:2);
%           \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\x}
            \path[name intersections={of=\x and a,by=s\x}];
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course I could manually type the intersetions, but can I use the comman in a `foreach loop`, too?

Comment: +1 but please wrap the `\x` in braces such that it compiles: `\path[name intersections={of={\x} and a,by=s\x}];` otherwise the space after `\x` gets eaten and Ti*k*Z does not see the `and`.

Comment: @marmot Alternative: `of={a and \x}`, so you don't need these ugly braces ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually name paths in such a way that they do not end with a macro. That way I am save if I compute the intersection between two paths with a macro.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip[draw] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
        \path[name path=a] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
      \draw[name path=b] (1.5,1.5) --+ (-2,2);
          \path[name intersections={of=a and b,by=s}];
      \node[fill=red,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (s) {};
        \foreach \x in {0,10,...,350}
        {
            \draw[name path=\x-path,shift={(1.5,1.5)}] (0,0) -- (\x:2);
%           \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\x}
            \path[name intersections={of=\x-path and a,by=s\x}];
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without any intersections:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
    \foreach \rot in {0,90,180,270}
      \foreach \x in {-40,-30,...,40} 
        \draw[->] (1.5,1.5) --++([rotate=\rot]\x : {1.5/cos(\x)});
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Arrows touching the right side of the rectangle can be easily drawn as `\draw[->] (1.5,1.5) --++(\x : {1.5/cos(\x)})`, where each arrow at angle `\x` has length `1.5/cos(\x)`. Then, we should repeat this for the remaining upper, left, and bottom sides of the rectangle, the outer `\foreach` loop does this by rotating arrows at the respective angles.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following (switch `a` and `\x`):

[image: intersections]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip[draw] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
        \path[name path=a] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
%       \draw[name path=b] (1.5,1.5) --+ (-2,2);
%           \path[name intersections={of=a and b,by=s}];
%       \node[fill=red,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (s) {};
        \foreach \x in {0,10,...,350}
        {
            \draw[name path=\x,shift={(1.5,1.5)}] (0,0) -- (\x:2);
%           \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\x}
            \path[name intersections={of=a and \x, by=s\x}];
            \draw[->] (1.5,1.5)-- (s\x);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```